# Launch the new "Scanning" settings activity on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, settings, android-6.0-marshmallow

The goal is to programmatically get to the Settings activity in Android that controls the option that used to be "Wi-Fi scanning always available" in the Advanced Wi-Fi settings prior to Android M. I used to get to this activity as follows:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS));
```

The setting has now moved under Settings -> Location -> Scanning (overflow menu). There doesn't seem to be a constant defined under Settings for the new page. How can I get the user to this new screen from my app?

I found the relevant preference fragment at com.android.settings.location.ScanningSettings.java. I think it's used by SettingsActivity to launch this preference panel?

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/location/ScanningSettings.java

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the user to this new screen from my app?

Unfortunately you can't, there isn't an action that open that fragment.

Your best bet is to open the Location settings with this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

and let the user open the overflow menu and select `Scanning`.

Another possible solution could be prompt the request directly from your app:

[image]

First check the state of Wi-Fi scanning, than show the dialog if it's disabled:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wi-Fi scanning is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE), MY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Then in `onActivityResult` check what user has chosen:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User has enabled Wi-Fi scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User has denied Wi-Fi scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is essentially what I'm doing right now. I was hoping there was a way to get directly to that screen as instructing the user to go through the overflow menu is a little cumbersome. In my app I'm actually trying to disable WiFi scanning, but nice to see there is a direct way to enable it with ACTION_REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE.

Comment: Is it something similar for Bluetooth scanning? For example, to do it manually in Android Pie is: Open Android settings -->go to Location --> Advanced --> Scanning. How can I access that bluetooth option by code?